# Two forms in html page using flask, only one form submission taking place

Tags: html, jquery, flask

I have two forms in html page, both are for signing in, one is for students and one is for teachers.
I am making a website using Flask and HTML5. My Problem is that only my student login is working, not the teacher login part help me out! is there any issue with the code or Flask? that it can take only one form values?

HTML CODE:

```
<script src="/static/js/signin.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/signinteacher.js"></script>

<div class="w3-row">
      <form class="w3-col s6 w3-padding-large w3-border-right w3-rightbar" style="height:570px" action="/validatestudentlogin" method="post">
        <h3><b>STUDENT LOGIN</b></h3>
        <label for="inputMoodle" class="w3-text-teal w3-section"><b>Moodle ID</b></label>
        <input id="number" class="w3-input w3-border w3-light-grey" type="text" name="inputMoodle" id="inputMoodle" style="width:50%" required autofocus><br>

        <label for="inputPassword" class="w3-text-teal w3-section"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-light-grey" type="password" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" style="width:50%" required><br>

        <button id="btnSignIn1" class="w3-btn w3-blue-grey w3-section" type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>

      <form class="w3-col s6 w3-padding-large" >
        <h3><b>TEACHER LOGIN</b></h3>
        <label for="inputTeacher" class="w3-text-teal w3-section"><b>Teacher ID</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-light-grey" type="text" name="inputTeacher" id="inputTeacher" style="width:50%" required autofocus><br>

        <label for="inputPassword1" class="w3-text-teal w3-section" for="pwd"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-light-grey" type="password" name="inputPassword1" id="inputPassword1" style="width:50%" required><br>

        <button id="btnSignIn2" class="w3-btn w3-blue-grey w3-section" type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>

    </div>
```

signinteacher.js

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnSignIn2').click(function(){
        console.log("This is working so far");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/validateteacherlogin',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

app.py

```
@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    if session.get('user'):
        return render_template('dashboard.html')
    else:
        return render_template('error.html',error = 'Unauthorized Access')

@app.route('/validatestudentlogin',methods=['POST'])
def validatestudentlogin():
    try:
        _moodleid = request.form['inputMoodle']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']        


        con = mysql.connect()
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.callproc('sp_validateLogin',(_moodleid,))
        data = cursor.fetchall()

        username=data[0][1]

        if len(data) > 0:
            if check_password_hash(str(data[0][2]),_password):
                session['user'] = data[0][0]
                return render_template('dashboard.html', moodleid= username)
            else:
                return render_template('error.html',error = 'Invalid Moodle ID or  wrong Password.')
        else:
            return render_template('error.html',error = 'Invalid Moodle ID or wrong Password.')


    except Exception as e:
        return render_template('error.html',error = str(e))
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        con.close()

@app.route('/teacherportal')
def dashboard1():
    if session.get('user'):
        return render_template('teacher_home.html')
    else:
        return render_template('error.html',error = 'Unauthorized Access'

@app.route('/validateteacherlogin',methods=['POST'])
def validateteacherlogin():
    try:
        _teacherid = request.form['inputTeacher']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword1']        


        con = mysql.connect()
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.callproc('sp_validateTeacherLogin',(_teacherid,))
        data = cursor.fetchall()

        username = data[0][1]


        if len(data) > 0:
            if check_password_hash(str(data[0][2]),_password):
                session['user'] = data[0][0]
                return render_template('teacher_home.html', moodleid= username)
            else:
                return render_template('error.html',error = 'Invalid Moodle ID or  wrong Password.')
        else:
            return render_template('error.html',error = 'Invalid Moodle ID or wrong Password.')


    except Exception as e:
        return render_template('error.html',error = str(e))
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        con.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have forgot to include the action and method attributes in your teacher login form in your html code. You'll need to add those.